# Laravel How to put custom validation messsage to validation bag?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.6

How do I put error message from external validator to message bag?
The thing is: I get the error response from validator from my API, I get the error message which I would like to push to existing validator on my page.

So, I have a form that is validated either from laravel validator on my page and API validator.

What I have tried was:

`dd(ValidationException::withMessages([
    'email' => $errors->email,
]));` where `$errors->email` is just an error message. But, it does not work the same as if it would be validated internally on the local project, the validation messages are not translated and so on...

As well, I have tried

```
throw ValidationException::withMessages([
      $validator->errors()->add('email', $errors->email[0])
]);
```

Where it got closer  to the solution:
In `ValidationException` I have instance of the exception but the message property is too nested:

{

```
"validator": {
     "messages": {
         "0" => [
             0 => MessageBag(2)
          ]
      }
   }
}
```

The messages are too nested and the still do not behave the same as the local ones.

If I am not clear enough I can provide further explanation.

EDIT:

To get the errors from the API I use:

`$errors = $response->getErrors()->email;` which gives me:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#784 ▼
    +"code": 42252
    +"message": "The email has already been taken."
  }
]
```

so I cannot use `$response->getErrors()->email->first()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for setting the error first:

```
ValidationException::withMessages([
    "email" => $errors->email->first()
]);
```

I'm more interested however in how you are choosing to display back the error.

Remember, don't use key accessors in Laravel to access objects in collections, and don't convert them to arrays. Eloquent and Collection methods are almost universally available on almost any collection object through facade inheritance, and are super useful.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Edit: Also, perhaps search and re-read the "Named Error Bags" section on this page, and "Custom Error Messages" section. They may provide you the trigger to find your solution if mine does not get you closer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post exception body from the API I get. I will update the question.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually trying to put array of response in the `email message`. Your code worked. I actually had to do a bit more changes but it was due to other things. Spent a lot of time doing a trivial thing but it was interesting walkthrough :)

Comment: Happy I could help

Answer (score 2):

use in this way.

```
    throw  \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::withMessages([
         'email' => 'Your validation message'
   ]);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post exception body from the API I get. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use **Form Request Validation**

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation)

For example:

```
class UpdateName extends BaseRequest {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
        'name.required' => 'Your name is required or any custom msg',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your own request validator with `$ php artisan make:request MyNewRequestName`

```
class MyNewRequestName extends BaseRequest {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'input_field' => 'required|integer',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'input_field.required' => 'This field is required',
            'input_field.integer'  => 'This field must contain integers only',
        ];
    }
}
```

And then, in your controller:

```
public function update( MyNewRequestName $request )
{
    //... another code here
}
```